# how to define keyCode or which or key or code properties for keyboard event

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, phantomjs, node-modules

As per my requirement, we need to write test specs for hot keys (say shift+1+L -- upload file).In my method i have written something like below

```
    public static SHIFTKEY      : number = 16;
    this.keys = {};

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    var code = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (code === KeyCodeConst.SHIFTKEY || (this.keys[KeyCodeConst.SHIFTKEY] && trackedKeys[code])) {
    if (!this.keys[code]) {
    this.keys[code] = true;
    this.keysCount++;
    }
    if (this.keysCount === 3) {
        alert('call the method which is required');
    }
    }
    if (!trackedKeys[code]) {
    this.keysCount = 0;
    }
    });
```

Now in my spec file i am trying to write a test case for this like below

```
      describe('Add Event Listener', () => {
           beforeEach(() => {
               viewModel = new viewModel();
               spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();
           });
           it('check the combination of keys are called', () => {
               keyPress(16);
               keyPress(49);
               keyPress(76);
               expect(viewModel.keys[KeyCodeConst.SHIFTKEY]).toBeTruthy();          
           });
           function keyPress(keyCodeVal) {
               var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
               try {
                   Object.defineProperty(keyboardEvent, 'keyCode', {'value': keyCodeVal});
               } catch (err){
                   console.log(err);
               }
               keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keydown',true,false,window,'',0,'',false,'');
               document.body.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
           }
       });
```

While running the build , i am getting an error like below and it is giving an build error like below

```
    Attempting to change value of a readonly property.
    at defineProperty (--some url--)
    at keyPress (--some url--)
```

Is there a way where we can send the pressed key value to the method ,apart from  keyCode or which. As per the MDN guidelines i observed that these are readonly attributes .I tried using key but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your method without actually triggering a keydown event, you might seperate the logic of getting the pressed key out of your function and in your tests just feed it with the pressed key codes you like to test.

To actually test `keydown` events, try this function which takes the element to dispatch the `keydown` event to and the `keyCode` value (adjusted to phantom-js):

```
    function triggerKeyDown(element, value) {
        var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
        e.initEvent('keydown', true, false);
        Object.defineProperty(e, 'keyCode', {'value': value});
        element.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. In order test the keydown events i need to create an element in before each .something like this--$('body').append("<input id='fixture' type='text'/>"); which will not serve my purpose

Comment: Property 'KeyboardEvent' does not exist on type 'Window'.-- I am getting this error. I checked the library it didn't exist.

Comment: I see, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) says the constructor is not available in all browsers. Maybe you have more luck with [the input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)